# No slot (not A or B) selected but can get to bootloader screen and use fastboot

Tags: fastboot, bootloader

long story short I messed up my phone trying to get TWRP/root/magisk on my razer 1 phone (I can provide gruesome details if requested). I can fastboot and get to the bootloader screen. I seem to be stuck, I can't do anything since I have no slot selected on my phone. Any thoughts on how to get a slot selected or to repair this in general? I appreciate any help, thank you very much.

```
C:\Razer\platform-tools>fastboot flash boot twrp-3.2.2-0-cheryl.img && fastboot reboot
fastboot: error: Failed to identify current slot

C:\Razer\platform-tools>fastboot --set-active=a
Setting current slot to 'a'                        FAILED (remote: 'set_active failed')
fastboot: error: Command failed

C:\Razer\platform-tools>fastboot --set-active=b
Setting current slot to 'b'                        FAILED (remote: 'set_active failed')
fastboot: error: Command failed

C:\Razer\platform-tools>fastboot getvar current-slot
current-slot:
Finished. Total time: 0.001s
```

Comment: If this a typo? `fastboot flash boot twrp-3.2.2-0-cheryl.img` usually you use `fastboot flash` or `fastboot boot` but not both at the same time. In your case I recommend only to use `fasboot boot` as it may work without an active selected slot.

Comment: @Robert active slot still needs to be selected for `/system`, `/vendor` etc.

Comment: @IrfanLatif But a recovery should be able to work without. Otherwise the situation of the asker would be a total dead lock aka bricked device.

Comment: @Robert without slot selection recovery too won't be able to know which `/system` and which `/vendor` to mount or flash. And A/B devices have no recovery partition officially. Even the `fastboot` is part of `aboot` or `abl` which is `abl_a` or `abl_b`. So `fastboot` itself is loaded from a slot. But it's only the bootloader which sets active slot to boot from on next reboot. If slot selection doesn't work, flashing factory firmware through `fastboot` or at even low level service mode would be the only option. But I haven't played with this practically, so cannot be sure.